Verbs followed by gerund/infinites
So naturally, it depends on the verb itself whether it should be followed by an infinitive or gerund form- hovewer there are cases in which depending on which form you use, you get a diffrent meaning but in other cases the meaning stays the same. Are there any golden rules? Also based on this list:
https://www.engvid.com/english-resource/verbs-followed-by-gerunds-and-infinitives/
The verb "offer" should be followed with an infinitve form. My question is: what happens if I try to construct a sentence like this:
"I offered taking her to the airport"
(even though I know, that it should go like "I offered to take her to the airport")
I expect that anyone with basic level will understand me- my question is how do you know if the meaning of the sentence changes based on different form of the verb? Will the meaning change at all? Why?

This question is similar to: Any differences between "The police observed the man entering the bank." and "The police observed the man enter the bank. ". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // There are several other threads which cover this; for instance, ...

at The choice between the {ing form} and the infinitive in a cetain construction is found  'Many verbs catenate
(Appendix:English catenative verbs - Wiktionary) and take the bare infinitive, the to-infinitive, or the -ing form rather unpredictably ...'. I'm afraid you have to learn how individual verbs are treated (and this can slowly change over time).

Ludwig has 'The phrase "offered taking" is not a grammatically correct or commonly used phrase in written English.' I'd avoid it, but would be far from shocked to see "I offered taking her to the airport" nowadays: I'd say it's becoming idiomatic (and hence acceptable).

There's never much difference in meaning, it's just a shade of meaning - it's not like the difference between "I will take you to the airport" and "I won't take you to the airport". So it won't make a big difference. As to how you know, a good dictionary with lots of usage examples is a start.

@StuartF I stopped smoking and I stopped to smoke comes close :)
